# On the structure of some subsets of the unit interval specified by binary expansion

Tags: probability-theory

How to prove that $\{\omega : |\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_i(\omega)-\frac{1}{2}|\geq \epsilon_n\}$ consist of finitely disjoint union of intervals (where $\epsilon_n$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence converging to $0$? where $d_i(\omega)$ is the $i$-th digit in the binary expansion of $\omega$.v Is it true even ? I see this claimed in some probability theory book.

Comment: Is $n$ fixed on your set?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(\varepsilon_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset (0,\infty)$ an arbitrary (but fixed) sequence. Set

$$A_n := \left\{\omega \in [0,1]; \left| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n d_i(\omega)-\frac{1}{2} \right| \geq \varepsilon_n \right\}, \qquad n \in \mathbb{N}$$

For fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$, consider the dyadic numbers

$$\omega_k := k \cdot 2^{-n}, \qquad k=0,\ldots,2^n$$

For any $\omega \in [\omega_k,\omega_{k+1})$ the first $n$ digits of the binary expansion of $\omega$ coincide with these of $\omega_k$, i.e. $d_i(\omega)=d_i(\omega_k)$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. Therefore,

$$[\omega_k,\omega_{k+1}) \in A_n \Leftrightarrow \omega_k \in A_n.$$

for $k=0,\ldots,2^n-1$. Consequently,

$$A_n = \bigcup_{k \in \{0,\ldots,2^n-1\}: \omega_k \in A_n} [\omega_k,\omega_{k+1})$$

Comment: How can it not depend on $\epsilon_n$ ?.

Comment: @Prasenjit Obviously, it depends on $\varepsilon_n$ whether $\omega_k \in A_n$ or $\omega_k \notin A_n$. Therefore, the representation as union of intervals depends on $\varepsilon_n$.